# 502 error with Nginx and Uwsgi, socket not found

Tags: python-3.x, nginx, ubuntu-16.04, uwsgi, digital-ocean

I've followed **[this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04)** on how to set up Nginx and Uwsgi on an Ubuntu droplet to have it be internet facing. I've done all the necessary setup;  running the command `uwsgi --socket 0.0.0.0:5000 --protocol=http -w wsgi:app` from a terminal works fine. It causes my site to be served on the proper domain name, on port 5000 (http://who.would.win:5000). This isn't ideal, so I'm trying to set it up to A) have it be detached, without me needing to manually run the command, and B) to have it not need port 5000 at the end.

I followed the rest of the tutorial, and have not been able to get it working properly. The source code of the Python application, which works just fine, is [here](https://github.com/ironohki/whowouldwin/tree/d3xus_stylesheetupdating). It's running off of my branch.

*/home/whowouldwin/myproject/myproject.ini*

```
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi:app

logto = /var/log/uwsgi/%n.log

master = true
processes = 5

socket = myproject.sock
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true

die-on-term = true
```

*/etc/systemd/system/myproject.service*

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI instance to serve myproject
After=network.target

[Service]
User=whowouldwin
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/whowouldwin/myproject
Environment="PATH=/home/whowouldwin/myproject/myprojectenv/bin"
ExecStart=/home/whowouldwin/myproject/myprojectenv/bin/uwsgi --ini myproject.ini

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

*/etc/nginx/sites-available/myproject*

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 159.89.137.109;

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:///home/whowouldwin/myproject/myproject.sock;
    }
}
```

I am trying to proxy my original IP address, 159.89.137.109, to the domain name http://who.would.win. When visiting the IP address as-is, I get the following error in `/var/log/nginx/error.log`. It also shows a 502 Bad Gateway error on the browser.

> 2018/06/03 01:32:55 [crit] 12288#12288: *7 connect() to unix:///home/whowouldwin/myproject/myproject.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: XXXXXX, server: 159.89.137.109, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:///home/whowouldwin/myproject/myproject.sock:", host: "159.89.137.109"

I don't get this error when I access it through http://who.would.win. It instead shows the generic "Welcome to Ngnix!" page, and no errors, though the views are being logged in `/var/log/nginx/access.log` as 200.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are (at least) two issues with your current configuration:

1) In your nginx config you set `server_name 159.89.137.109;` so nginx will serve your website only when accessed as `http://159.89.137.109`. Changing it to `server_name who.would.win` should address that (or make it the default server entry, see `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`)

2) In your uwsgi ini file, try setting the socket path as an absolute path, something like `socket = /home/whowouldwin/myproject/myproject.sock`

Comment: 1) I did that, and now it's showing 502 bad gateway on http://who.would.win, which is what it was showing on the IP address. It's an improvement, since it's now reflecting what I'm actually trying to show I think. 2) I'm not using gunicorn at all; should I be using it?

Comment: Same error as before, if I set the socket to an absolute path. `2018/06/03 15:56:55 [crit] 1414#1414: *1 connect() to unix:///home/whowouldwin/myproject/myproject.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: XXXXX, server: who.would.win, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:///home/whowouldwin/myproject/myproject.sock:", host: "who.would.win"`

Comment: I notice the first part of the error has `unix:///home...` while the second has `uwsgi://unix:///home...` Is that meaningful?

Comment: Ah maybe. Can you try in your nginx config `uwsgi_pass unix:/home/whowouldwin/myproject/myproject.sock;`  (just one slash after `unix:`, not three`

Comment: Is the socket file there? What does `ls -la /home/whowouldwin/myproject/myproject.sock` show while the python process is running.

Comment: `ls: cannot access '/home/whowouldwin/myproject/myproject.sock': No such file or directory`. I was under the impression that file would be automatically created...How should I make that file? What goes in it?

Comment: uwsgi should have created the socket file when the process started. Did you restart it after hanging the socket config to the absolute path? Can you confirm it's up by running `ps faux` an see if the process is there?

Comment: Ok, so it doesn't look like it's running at all. Trying to run it (`sudo service uwsgi start`) says the service isn't even installed, so I'm not sure why the first command I had (`uwsgi --socket 0.0.0.0:5000 --protocol=http -w wsgi:app`) would work if uwsgi was not installed. Am I missing an installation step?

Comment: Well, you got to decide how you want to set this up. Either run uwsgi on port 5000 and procy with nginx via http or use the unix socket (that's what's in your ini file which doesn't seem to be used at all.
See here for more information: http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/WSGIquickstart.html

Comment: That got me where I was going in terms of properly setting up uwsgi without it needing to be on a port. Now I just have to start it on startup. Thank you so much!

Comment: how to solve it, I am using the same tutorial and have same issue. could you tell me in detail @D3xus